# Convert a 64bit little endian integer to number

Tags: javascript, node.js, 64-bit, buffer, endianness

first of all I'm sorry for the dumb question but I'm new with nodejs.
I read from a socket a 64bit little endian signed integer, and put it on a Buffer, so let's say i have the number 256 represented as:

```
<Buffer 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00>
```

Since the Buffer class has only readInt32LE and readUInt32LE how can i convert this buffer to its equivalent js number, using 32 bit operations ?
Should i read two 32bit big endian numbers and then somehow bitwise or them ? should i read them little endian ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ECMA Section 8.5 - Numbers](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5)

> Note that all the positive and negative integers whose magnitude is no greater than 2<sup>53</sup> are representable in the Number type (indeed, the integer 0 has two representations, +0 and −0).

Javascript uses internally 64 bit floating numbers, wich means you can only represent exactly numbers up to 2<sup>53</sup>, or 9007199254740992. If it's ok for you, you can use following code to read 64 bit signed/unsigned int into 64 bit float:

```
function readUInt64(buff, offset) {
  return buff.readInt32LE(offset) + 0x100000000*buff.readUInt32LE(offset + 4);
}

function readInt64(buff, offset) {
   var word0 = buff.readUInt32LE(offset);
   var word1 = buff.readUInt32LE(offset+4);
   if (!(word1 & 0x80000000))
      return word0 + 0x100000000*word1;
   return -((((~word1)>>>0) * 0x100000000) + ((~word0)>>>0) + 1);
}
```

If you need exact representation - use [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js) library

```
function readUInt64(buff, offset) {
   var word0 = buff.readUInt32LE(offset);
   var word1 = buff.readUInt32LE(offset+4);
   return new BigNumber(word0).plus(new BigNumber(word1).times(0x100000000));
}
```